# Change boolean value onClick in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I'm trying to change the value of a boolean from an object imported from a JSON file in React. I want the offers.availability value to change to false after clicking on the "add to cart" button.
Here's my code:

```
function App() {

class App  {

constructor () {
  this.state = {
     offers: [],
  }
  this.handleToggle = this.handleToggle.bind(this);
  }

      componentDidMount() {
        this.state.setState({ offers: Data });
      }

      handleToggle (offers) {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          offers: prevState.offers.map(prevOffer => {
            if (prevOffer.availability === offers.availability) {
              return {
                availability: prevOffer.availability,
                isTrue: !prevOffer.isTrue
              }
          }

          return prevOffer;
        })}));
      }        
    }
 

  return (
    <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          {Data.offers.map(offers => {

            return(
              <div key={offers.make + offers.model + offers.engine + offers.photo} className="col-sm-4">
                
                <div className="card" >
                  <img src={offers.photo} className="card-img-top" alt={offers.make + ' ' + offers.model } width="100%"/>
                  <div className="card-body pt-0 px-0">
                    <div className="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between mb-0 px-3 p-3 mid">
                      <div className="d-flex flex-column">
                        <h4>{offers.make} {offers.model}</h4>
                      </div>
                      <div className="d-flex flex-column">
                      <button type="button" className="btn btndelete"><FaTrash /></button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between px-3">
                      <div className="d-flex flex-column"><span className="text-muted">Engine: {offers.engine}</span></div>
                      <div className="d-flex flex-column">
                        {offers.availability.toString()}
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="mx-3 mt-3 mb-2 d-grid gap-2">
                      {offers.availability
                       ? <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary addtocartbtn" onClick={() => Data.offers.handleToggle(offers)}>
                         <small>Add to cart</small>
                         </button>
                       : <button type="button" className="btn btn-disabled"  onClick={console.log('???')}><small>Currently unavailabe</small></button>
                      }
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>



               </div>
            )
          }) }
        </div>
      </div>
  )}

export default App;
```

I tried to toggle the boolean value but I currently get a ".offers.handleToggle is not a function" error after clicking.
I'm new to this so please don't judge if I did something really stupid here :) What could be the possible solution to this?

Comment: Hello and welcome on Stackoverflow. To help us helping you can you please minimize your code example removing everyhing (classnames etc) which is not related to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use Data.offers.handleToggle. From what I see, Data.offers is an array of objects which they don't have a function handleToggle defined.

However, you are defining a function handleToggle on the App component that looks good. It should work if you change `onClick={() => Data.offers.handleToggle(offers)}` with either `onClick={() => handleToggle(offers)}` or `onClick={() => this.handleToggle(offers)}`

**UPDATE**

After running your code I saw the component is defined as a mix of a functional component and a class component. First, decide what you are going to use and then fix the errors 1 by 1. The constructor for example is missing the props, there are onclicks that are not well defined and a few more things.

Here is your code if used as a class component.

```
import { Component } from "react";

export class App extends Component<{}, { offers: any[] }> {
  constructor(props: {}) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      offers: [],
    };
    this.handleToggle = this.handleToggle.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ offers: Data });
  }

  handleToggle(offers: any) {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      offers: prevState.offers.map((prevOffer) => {
        if (prevOffer.availability === offers.availability) {
          return {
            availability: prevOffer.availability,
            isTrue: !prevOffer.isTrue,
          };
        }

        return prevOffer;
      }),
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          {this.state.offers.map((offers) => {
            return (
              <div
                key={offers.make + offers.model + offers.engine + offers.photo}
                className="col-sm-4"
              >
                <div className="card">
                  <img
                    src={offers.photo}
                    className="card-img-top"
                    alt={offers.make + " " + offers.model}
                    width="100%"
                  />
                  <div className="card-body pt-0 px-0">
                    <div className="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between mb-0 px-3 p-3 mid">
                      <div className="d-flex flex-column">
                        <h4>
                          {offers.make} {offers.model}
                        </h4>
                      </div>
                      <div className="d-flex flex-column">
                        <button type="button" className="btn btndelete">
                          <FaTrash />
                        </button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between px-3">
                      <div className="d-flex flex-column">
                        <span className="text-muted">
                          Engine: {offers.engine}
                        </span>
                      </div>
                      <div className="d-flex flex-column">
                        {offers.availability.toString()}
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="mx-3 mt-3 mb-2 d-grid gap-2">
                      {offers.availability ? (
                        <button
                          type="button"
                          className="btn btn-primary addtocartbtn"
                          onClick={() => this.handleToggle(offers)}
                        >
                          <small>Add to cart</small>
                        </button>
                      ) : (
                        <button
                          type="button"
                          className="btn btn-disabled"
                          onClick={() => console.log("???")}
                        >
                          <small>Currently unavailabe</small>
                        </button>
                      )}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

You just need to define the offers type and a FaTrash component

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the answer. Your first solution gives me an error that says " Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'handleToggle')" after clicking on the button and the second one "'handleToggle' is not defined" when trying to run the app.

Comment: I updated the answer, the component was defined as a mix of class component and function component

Comment: It still gives me "prevState.offers.map is not a function" error